# ALTbeacon use in Android Module

Tags: android, module, altbeacon

Hi I want to use **ALTbeacon** in **Android Module**. This is not a problem, ALTbeacon is a great library.

However:
If user/system kill the app, which use my **Android Module** I want to regenerate `RangeNotifier`.

I read official documentation: https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/background_launching.html

But they use `AndroidProximityReferenceApplication` extend **`Application`** but in Android Module it is not possible to extend from `Application`

Has anyone solved something similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Android Beacon Library will resume scanning for beacons [even after the app gets killed](https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/resume-after-terminate.html) using one of two techniques:

1. On Android 8+ it uses the JobScheduler with a persistent beacon ScanJob every 15 minutes that runs again even if your app is terminated.
2. On Android 4.3-7.x, it uses an IntentService for scanning with the START_STICKY flag that causes the OS to re-launch the service automatically if the BeaconService is killed.

Both techniques don't specifically require the use of an Android Application class, but they do need:

(a) the appropriate entries in the [AndroidManifest.xml](https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library/blob/2.16.1/lib/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml).  If you are building your own library, you can put those same two entries in its manifest, and consuming libraries will inherit those entries during manifest merging.

(b) some kind of initialization method call to start up the beacon scanning when the app is launched.  For this, you can simply instruct your library's users to make this initialization call from their own Application class' onCreate method.  Inside this initialization call you can simply set up a RegionBootrap as if it were in the  Application class itself.  (There are other ways to kick off this initialization when the app starts up, but this is the easiest.)

I have built a number of custom libraries based on the Android Beacon Library and this is the technique I always use.